# VBA to move ppt object to a specific location

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint, shapes

I am using VBA to push calculations from Access into charts, graphs and tables in a template powerpoint presentation. The objects are manipulated with tables within Access for specific names, font size, chart type etc. The problem I am running into is moving my named objects within the powerpoint. Since I am using a powerpoint template I have specific slides that I need to move the objects to. Some of the slides have room for multiple shape/objects and are not necessarily in a specific slide order. The shapes are named within the presentation. I cannot find a command to move an object/shape to an identified location.

The closest thing I have found is something similar to :

```
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).MoveTo to Pos:=1
```

However, this moves the entire slide and not just the table, graph or chart. Again, since the slide order may change I need to use the name of the object and the name of the shape in the slide to connect the two. Any command I should research would be helpful! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The position and size of shapes on a PPT slide is controlled by the .Top, .Left, .Height and .Width properties of the shape (specified in Points, 72 points to the inch).

Assuming you know the slide's index and the name of the shape, this would move it to 1" from the top and 1" from the left edge of the slide:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("YourShapeName")
  .Top = 72
  .Left = 72
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to be able to point to a location by name in case it is moved around in the template by the user. I may have to go the coordinate route though...

Comment: Side/Related Question: Is it possible to know at which coordinate the user clicked on the slide?

Comment: There may be a Windows API function that'd help with this; while you can, I think, get the cursor position via VBA, you can't trap mouse-click events.

Comment: You might also consider adding tags to the shapes whose positions you want to "protect". The tags could store each shape's top/left/height/width properties. A fairly simple routine could check each shape on each slide and if it contains positioning tags, move the shape to the desired position.